# WordPress mark BuddyPress custom notifications as read on clicking

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have created a custom notification in Buddypress. Whenever a new Topic is started, it is sent for moderation and all the moderators are sent the notification and email to approve the post. The notification looks like this (clicking on it takes to the topic where a moderator can approve/reject the post)-

[image: custom notifications]

When I click on the notification, it isn't marked as read. I understand that the notification link should have a 'bbp_mark_read' action for it to be marked as read. But I am not able to find proper way to add the action to the notification url. Here is my code-

```
// Display notification.
add_filter( 'bp_notifications_get_notifications_for_user', 'bbms_moderation_alert_notifications', 10, 5 );

function bbms_moderation_alert_notifications( $action, $item_id, $secondary_item_id, $total_items, $format = 'string' ) {

    // New custom notifications
    if ( 'bbms_moderation_alert_action' === $action ) {
        
        $post = get_post( $item_id ); //$item_id represents ID of the Topic
        $author_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author);
        $custom_title = '[Moderate] ' .bp_core_get_user_displayname( $post->post_author ) . ' created a Topic "' . get_the_title( $item_id ) . '"';
        $custom_link  = get_permalink( $post ); //Need to create a wp_nonce_url with bbp_mark_topic action here
        $custom_text = '[Moderate] ' .bp_core_get_user_displayname( $post->post_author ) . ' created a Topic "' . get_the_title( $item_id ) . '"';

        // WordPress Toolbar
        if ( 'string' === $format ) {
            $return = apply_filters( 'bbms_moderation_alert_filter', '<a href="' . esc_url( $custom_link ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $custom_title ) . '">' . esc_html( $custom_text ) . '</a>', $custom_text, $custom_link );
        // Deprecated BuddyBar
        } else {
            $return = apply_filters( 'bbms_moderation_alert_filter', array(
                'text' => $custom_text,
                'link' => $custom_link
            ), $custom_link, (int) $total_items, $custom_text, $custom_title );
        }

        return $return;
    }

    return $action;

}
```

I need to change $custom_link in above code. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I actually made this for invitations to the event (custom post type), in my case I can get multiple invitations about the same event from different users, but it will work in your case too.

Function which we will use:

```
bp_notifications_mark_notifications_by_item_id();
```

It can be found in [bp-notifications-functions.php](https://github.com/buddypress/buddypress/blob/be7398c7fa899d69d10331c3a963314d204d12ee/src/bp-notifications/bp-notifications-functions.php#L549) or [buddyboss functions reference](https://www.buddyboss.com/resources/reference/functions/bp_notifications_mark_notifications_by_item_id/).

**First** you need to prepare the url.

```
$args = array(
    'action'        => 'custom_action',
    'item_id'       => $item_id,
    'secondary_id'  => $secondary_item_id
);

// Add the args to the URL.
$custom_link = add_query_arg( $args, get_the_permalink($item_id) );
```

'action' can be anything.

You **don't** use nonce here, because it lasts only for 24 hours, if the user will check notification after that, your function to remove it, won't work.

**The second** function will handle the unmark of the notification:

```
function my_post_mark_read() {

   if (get_post_type() === 'my_post_slug') {
  
      if (isset($_GET['item_id']) && isset($_GET['secondary_id']) && isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'custom_action') {

         $user_id = get_current_user_id();
         $item_id = htmlentities($_GET['item_id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
         $component_name = 'my_component_name';
         $component_action = 'my_component_action';
         $secondary_item_id = htmlentities($_GET['secondary_id']);
         $is_new = 0;

         bp_notifications_mark_notifications_by_item_id( $user_id, $item_id, $component_name, $component_action, $secondary_item_id, $is_new );

      }
   }
}
add_action('wp', 'my_post_mark_read');
```

You don't need to get `$post` object for this function.
You can get post author name by id which is `$secondary_item_id`, like this:

```
$author_name = get_user_by('id', $secondary_item_id)->display_name;
```

But you never use it, instead you use `bp_core_get_user_displayname( $post->post_author )`, which again you can just get like this `bp_core_get_user_displayname( $secondary_item_id )`, without the need of `$post`.
Your `$custom_title` and `$custom_text` are the same. You should just use one variable instead of repeating yourself.